Can "show" be replaced by "present"?
The charts use the verb show. Is it good to use present instead?

The charts present the average percentages in typical meals of three
types of nutrients.



The issue is not show/present. It's the sentence overall. In any case, this is an editing question.Those are called pie charts. And I am sure you can find pie charts on the Internet that use both.

I‘m not asking you to edit a single word. Other words I use are exactly the same as the charts. I'm not rewriting the chart description. There is nothing to edit. The sentence doesn't have a problem because it's from my Cambridge book. I just want to know about "present".

First hits for "pie charts present", including an IELTS one: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+pie+charts+present%22&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1077US1078&oq=%22the+pie+charts+present%22&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQABiABDINCAIQABiGAxiABBiKBTINCAMQABiGAxiABBiKBTINCAQQABiGAxiABBiKBTINCAUQABiGAxiABBiKBTIKCAYQABiABBiiBDIKCAcQABiABBiiBDIKCAgQABiABBiiBNIBCTg3NjdqMGoxNagCCLACAQ&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

I think you should say pie charts because without it, the meaning can change.

I don't trust that site. That's why I ask here.

There are tons of examples that aren't IELTS: The pie charts present the relative abundances of the dominant species (≥5%) averaged for the selected time periods. [down the page of hits] But there are many more hits for pie charts show.

Hi! This asks "This example uses one word. Would another word be better?" That isn't really much to go on. Please edit to explain more about why you think "show" is not the best choice, or why "present" would be better, because "No, 'show' is fine" isn't a very helpful answer.

It's fine, there are other verbs too: The three piecharts illustrate/ show/ display/ represent/ present the average percentage of sodium, saturated fat and added sugars found in meals…

In most of the cases, you can interchangeably used them, even in the current case you can use present instead of show. The choice of either of them depends on the level of generality/formality of the context. Show is used in a more general case, whereas present would be more appropriate when you are in a more formal context such as a research paper and so on. Present is also a preferred choice when the size of audience is large, for instance, you would present (instead of show) a life size portrait of Mona Lisa in an auction.

+1 I like that last sentence. [laughs [nicely[)

Thanks, I could not think of any better analogy. :-)

Actually, I would argue that while both are acceptable, "show" is better in any setting. I guess I'll add an answer to explain more.

@AndyBonner, that's exactly what I am thinking about? My books use "show" for all charts. This makes my wonder if "show" is the best word choice here.
